# Stan - Mixture of Normals

Tags: rstan

I'm using RStan to fit a mixture of two normals.

```
data {
 int<lower = 1> K;
 int<lower = 1> N;
 real y[N];
}
parameters {
 simplex[K] theta;
 real mu[K];
 real<lower = 0> sigma;
}
model{
 real ps[K]; // place-holder for log component densities
 sigma ~ uniform(0.5, 1.5);
 mu ~ normal(0, 10);
 for (n in 1:N){
  for (k in 1:K) {
   ps[k] <- log(theta[k]) + normal_log(y[n], mu[k], sigma);
  }
  increment_log_prob(log_sum_exp(ps)); // log_sum_exp(lp1,lp2) =    log(exp(lp1) + exp(lp2))
  }
}
```

I'd like to add a condition that mu[1] is less than mu[2]. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: That uniform prior won't work because there are values that satisfy the declared constraint (e.g., 2), which are out of support.  Update the constraint to match the uniform at which point you don't need the uniform sampling statement.  Whatever you do, don't try to use the uniform to do rejection, which is what this program does.

Comment: @BobCarpenter, thanks very much, Bob. I thought I had removed my question from the user group - sorry for the redundant question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ordered type in Stan. Declare `mu` as `ordered[K] mu`.

Comment: This makes all the values ordered and the OP didn't say what K was or if they were all in order.  If K = 2, then you might want to use the log_mix() function.